# Local system date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a readonly field in HTML form. Here, I need to display the date (which comes from backend system) in the format which is relevant for the locale system of the user. This being an editable field, User may enter the date as per the system setting.

I was wondering how can I can get the system date format (i.e. it can be dd.MM.yyyy, MM/dd/YYYY, dd-MM-YYYY, YYYY-MM-dd based on the system settings in user's PC) using Javascript or jQuery.

Regards,

SAP Learner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You Can get system date using build in function in JS

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
document.write(today)

document.write("<br>")
// OR other solution

document.write(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0].replace('T',' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the HTML field is a HTML5 date type field. Depending of the browser and language locale the front end user format could be seen differently, but the underlying value is always defined by the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. Also, when a form containing a date field is posted, the server side will receive also this format.

Dates on Javascript are based on the object `Date`. But this, additional of the Calendar date, also includes time, microseconds and timezone. To get the current user system date browser formatted on the user locale, can be done using.

```
var dateLocale= new Date().toLocaleString();
```

If the date input by the user, using a date input field, getting just the value will give the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. However there is a way to retrieve the content using the method `valueAsDate`. This will return a `Date` object. However this Date object will have the time at 12:00 AM at GMT timezone. When you try to retrieve the locale date part, the content could be wrong because it's on the wrong timezone. To workaround the issue add the timezone offset minutes to the Date object to get you the correct locale time and date.

```
var dv=document.getElementById('date_field').valueAsDate;
dv.setMinutes(dv.getTimezoneOffset());
var datelocale=dv.toLocaleDateString;
```

Now you can do whatever you want with `datelocale` variable, but not try to put it back to a date input field as it could be incompatible. You could put it into a text input type or a hidden type.

Comment: Thanks..
However, my question still remains unanswered.|
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]; gave me date in yyyy-MM-dd format. However, how can I determine the dateformat setting of the user's system using this.. I have to format the date coming from backend to locale format in a date field as well as a text field.

Comment: I edited my answer to make clear that the language locale is independent when you are using the input date type. The only thing that is tricky is when you are using also time, because you need to take on consideration the timezone. But that is a different form input and it's not universally available on all the browsers.

Comment: On the other hand if what you want is see how the user computer date format is configured you could use `var a=new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0];`. But this format could be incompatible with the HTML5 date input controller.

Comment: Thanks for your responses..

How about var a=new Date().toLocaleDateString(); instead of var a=new Date().toLocaleString().split(',')[0];?

To be very specific, I am looking for the following:
If date format as per user system setting is 06/25/2018, I want the format as MM/dd/yyyy
If date format as per user system setting is 25.06.2018, I want the format as dd.MM.yyyy

So the program that I am looking for should give me MM/dd/yyyy or dd.MM.yyyy or whichever format the user uses in the system

Comment: You are right. If you are only interested on the date part `.toLocalDateString()` could avoid all the other extra code to exclude the time part. I think browsers are more reliable extracting the correct locale.
Question: Do you want to get "now" time of the user, or do you want to format an external date on the user locale to show to the users?

Comment: It can be either now time or a date entered by user.

Comment: I just update my answer to show both methods: now system date and value input by the user.